# Showing that v(f)=0 Implies a Function is Constant on a Torus for v = $\partial_1 +\lambda \partial_2$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

On a torus we are given the vector field: $ v=\partial_1 +\lambda \partial_2$, and asked to show that if $\lambda$ is irrational then $v(f)=0$ implies that f is constant. I know that if $\lambda$ is irrational then the integral curves of $v$ densely cover the torus and if f is constant on them then it has to be constant on the whole torus. But I don't see how to proceed to show that it's constant. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $t$ is the parameter along the integral curves of $v$, so that

$v = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}, \tag 1$

then

$v(f) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}; \tag 2$

thus if

$v(f) = 0, \tag 3$

then

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0, \tag 4$

showing $f$ is constant along these trajectories.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but does anything change in this argument if $\lambda$ is rational instead so the integral curves are closed?

Comment: Yes, you'll get $f$ periodic I think.  When $\lambda = p/q$ with $\gcd(p, q) = 1$, then the curves close after going around the torus $p$ times in one direction and $q$ times in the other.  So a function with $v(f) = 0$ is of period $2\pi /p$ in one direction and $2\pi /q$ in the other.  If I recall correctly . . . does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you

Comment: Well, if you like my answer you might upvote and/or accept it.  I would appreciate that.  Cheers!